# Primefaces datatable selection malfunctions after update

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, primefaces-datatable

I am facing a problem with the update of the datatable component in the primefaces. My goal is to update the datable and the selected row of the table to remain highlighted. Instead of this I have the following: The 1st, 3rd, 5th,... selected highlighted row stays selected after the update whereas the 2nd, 4th, 6th,...loses the selection. The expected behavior would be to have the selected rows remain selected. I use primefaces version 6.1 and Mojarra implementation jsf 2.2.12.

```
<p:dataTable id="table" value="#{view.Rows}" var="row"
                       selection="{view.selectedRow}"
                       selectionMode="single" rowKey="#{row.id}" rows="18" lazy="true"  paginator="true" paginatorPosition="top" >
              <p:columns value="#{view.columns.list}" var="Col"
                  <f:facet name="header">
                      <h:outputText value="#{col.title}" />
                  </f:facet>
                  <h:outputText value="#{col.value(row)}" />
              </p:columns>
          </p:dataTable>
          <p:poll interval="80" update ="table"/>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Did you check if it is by accident a CSS issue?

Comment: No, this was my first impression. I debugged this and the property(selectedRow) in the bean is set to null when I clicked the rows 2nd, 4th, 6th.